# Alerting Javascript array object shows empty

Tags: php, javascript, arrays

I am trying to send the `JavaScript` array to my `php`, but `php` gets empty []. 
It even shows like that in my browser. I have always sent `JSON` and had no problem, but now have this format.

I have this example that makes no sense...it's just a code to illustrate the issue:

```
var blah    = [];
var letters = ['a', 'b', 'c', 'd'];

for (var i = 0; i < letters.length; i++)
{
    blah[letters[i]] = i;
}
```

Inside `firebug DOM` it shows as follows:

```
blah      []
    a      0
    b      1
    c      2
    d      3
```

When I do

1. **`alert(blah)`**   ------------------------------- I get empty
2. **`alert(JSON.stringify(blah))`**             ----- I get []
3. **`alert(blah.a)`**    ---------------------------- I get 0

So how can I pass this object to `php`? Thanks

Comment: **Thank you for the answers and efforts. `rossipedia` answered first so I will accept his answer. Appreciate it**

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Instead of an array, try using an object.

So instead of:

```
var blah    = [];
```

Try

```
var blah    = {};
```

Comment: that example is only for illustration sake

Comment: Removed the example from my answer. The issue is that you're using an array when you should be using an object.

Answer (score 4):

Arrays are continuously numerically indexed. They do not have strings as key names.
What you want is an object `{}`, not an array `[]`.

Answer (score 2):

Can not assign key value collection in array. You need to work on objects:

```
var obj = {
    key1: value1,
    key2: value2
};
```

for converting array to string you can use:

```
var fruits = ["Banana", "Orange", "Apple", "Mango"];
fruits.toString();
```

with seperator:

```
var fruits = ["Banana", "Orange", "Apple", "Mango"];
var energy = fruits.join(" and ");
```

[Here is working Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/dEVTx/)

try this:

```
var blah    = {};
var letters = ['a', 'b', 'c', 'd'];

for (var i = 0; i < letters.length; i++)
{
    blah[letters[i]] = i;
}

alert(JSON.stringify(blah));
```

Comment: but what if my key is a variable, how should i assign then? Like this `fruits[key] = value`?

Answer (score 1):

I have answered this before. Anyway, `blah` is an array, but you are not using it as array, you are using it as a hashmap. Arrays work with indexes and maps work with keys. Any object in JS can also act like a map. For e.g

```
var obj = new Object();
obj.a = 10;
obj["b"] = 20;

var obj2 = function(){...}
obj2.foo = 10;
obj2.bar = "baz";
```

Similarly, `Array` is also and `Object` and can act like a map. But when you use the array like a map, its array is not utilized to store the elements. They just act like above. So the `length` of an Array is 0 even though it has properties attached to it.

What you must do is use Array methods like `push` and `pop` to populate and retrieve from it.